# Using Obscure and UnObscure...Am I doing this right?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

WP 7.5 app. I have two Storyboard animations - one on image and another on Text.

**Issue1:** When I move to next page and go back, the image and text blinks.

**Solution1:** So I added OnNavigateFrom and explicity Stop the animations and also reset any properties involved in animations to 0.

**Issue2:** Now say the screen goes to lock-mode and when I unlock it, since I set opacity of one of my element to 0 in OnNavigatedFrom the element is hidden, which actually should be visible until the user moves to next page.

**Solution2:** I handled Obscured and UnObscured handler like below in the code and added a flag to see if app is going to obscured mode, do not stop animation or reset properties.

```
public class Page2 :PhoneApplicationPage
    {
         private bool _isObscured = false;
         public Page2()
        {
            (Application.Current as App).RootFrame.Obscured += OnObscured;
            (Application.Current as App).RootFrame.Unobscured += OnUnobscured;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            //Stop animations and reset properties only if not going to obscure mode.
            if (!_isObscured)
            {
                //stop animaiton
                Storyboard1.Stop();
                Storyboard2.Stop();
                //Reset all transform properties to 0
                Text1.Opacity = 0;
                Image1.RenderTransform.SetValue(CompositeTransform.ScaleXProperty, 0.0);
                Image1.RenderTransform.SetValue(CompositeTransform.ScaleYProperty, 0.0);
            }
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        }

        void OnObscured(object sender, ObscuredEventArgs e)
        {
            Storyboard1.Pause();
            Storyboard2.Pause();
            _isObscured = true;
        }

        void OnUnobscured(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Storyboard1.Resume();
            Storyboard2.Resume();
            _isObscured = true;
        }
    }
```

**Question**: Is this the corret way to go or is there a better way? Can there be any certification issue for doing it this way?

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More easiest way is to add `IsLeave` boolean property and set it to true in click event that calls `NavigateTo` method. Also, stop animations in the same function too.

Than you can be sure that, that when you to come back, `IsLeave` property says you to perform animation or not.

`private bool IsLeave = false;`

```
 OnNavigatedTo()
 {
      if (IsLeave)
      {
           //We come back. Reset animations
           IsLeave = false;
      }
 }
```

.

```
 ClickEvent()
 {
      IsLeave = true;
      //Permorm all you need with animations. We leave this page
      NavigationService.NavigateTo()
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand that exactly? How is that going to help when screen locks i.e. obscured happens?

Comment: In this case, when screen is locked there is no opacity changes in OnNavigatedFrom method anymore. So, when you come back - all elements are still visible. And your Solution1 not produce Issue2, I think

Comment: I see. I will have to test that out. Also my NavigationService.NavigateTo() is inside of a customControl, which handles navigation via MouseLeftButtonDown of my image. I will try and update. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ku6opr. I integrated your logic in my page and seems to be working. I still have a doubts on Obscure/Unobsruce which I am going to ask in a new question.