# Is it required to pause the animation using Obscure while app is being interrupted?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

Coming from this previous question: [Using Obscure and UnObscure...Am I doing this right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623030/using-obscure-and-unobscure-am-i-doing-this-right)

1: Is it mandatory to pause the animation on my page when the app is interrupted by another app or screen lock?

And

2: When the app is deactivated or tombstoned I think all the animation stops by default correct? Or Do I need to stop them explicitly?

**Update:**
Two questions above yes/no and why? Trial and error would work if something was breaking but my app is working fine with the code I have or if I remove it. I want to know technical/architectural implications.

Comment: Can't you try this easily? If it doesn't crash, and you can return to the app successfully, then you're probably good.

Comment: [Trial and Error programming](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TrialAndErrorProgramming) can sometimes be an excellent way to understand how things work.

Comment: @willmel: I was looking for some technical explanation/resource that explains this. My app works but want to make sure I am doing it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my understanding of the guidelines.

First, for 1, let's separate it out a bit. All interruptions are not equal.

1. Obscure is when you get a phone call and your app is still running but not all of the screen is visible. For games it is recommended that the game automatically pause. For apps it is up to you. Just do what seems right for the state of your app at the time.
2. Screen lock

   1. If you do not run under the lock screen then it's basically the same as deactivation (see below)
   2. If you do run under the lock screen you are supposed to stop all animations and screen updating. It's to help conserve battery I believe.
3. When you said "interrupted by another app" did you mean toast? I don't think you get obscured from toast. Apps can't interrupt each other AFAIK.

For 2, when you get deactivated you don't know if you will be fast-app switched, tombstoned, or terminated.

1. In the case of fast-app switching, your animation should continue fine when you are activated and there is no reason I know of to pause the animations manually.
2. If you get tombstoned, or eventually terminated, your animations would have all been stopped anyway. No advantage to manually stopping them in that case either.

Comment: 3: Interrupted by app...I meant something like incoming call. I have a moving object from right-to left. When the screeen locks, I have to reset the position else upon unlock, the object won't move i.e. animation doesn't continue as expected with fast-app switching. I think it's case-by-case basis when should I handle it. Thanks for the detailed info.

Comment: Does the animation continue if you hit start and then hit the back button? The lock screen doesn't work like fast-app switching if you aren't specifically telling the system you are going to keep running under it. Are you running under the lockscreen in your case? Also there is a project-level property to tombstone upon deactivation - perhaps you have that set? ( http://www.ginktage.com/2011/10/how-to-enable-windows-phone-application-tombstone-in-emulator-when-debugging/ )

Comment: 1)I didn't get that question exactly but I stop the animation moving to next page and with Back button it should stop automatically correct, as the page is out of stack. 2) I don't know. I mean I am not doing anything explicit to exit the app. Do I need to to anything specific? I just stop my animation in NavigatedFrom event. 3) I am not sure of this project level tombstoning option, except the one thats's in VS but that is for Debug mode in Emulator correct? I am testing on a device, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Ok if you're testing on a device then you're fine I think. So in your NavigatedFrom, try *not* stopping your animation. Fast app-switching and the animation *should* (AFAIK) work if you don't manually stop it like that.

Comment: Actually I have to stop the animation and I do that using some flag variables. It causes weird things when I go to next page and use back to return. I actually have most of my stuff working. Need a bit more testing.

Comment: You will want to differentiate when you are navigating away because you pressed back, from when you are navigating away because the system is switching you out (fast-app switching, tombstoning, etc). You do that by using OnNavigatingFrom and checking e.NavigationMode (e is NavigatingCancelEventArgs). If NavigationMode is Back then go ahead and stop the animations, but otherwise don't. Try that and let me know.

Comment: Yes I am doing all that and everything is running fine. From my testing NavigationMode.Back will not work as it's considered Back even when returning from Obscured mode.

Comment: My bad...it is considered as New when returning from obscured. But in any case everything is working fine but had to put lot many checks to make it work. Thanks for all your help.